# Flatten 3rd level of array to create indexed array of associative rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten, array-merge

I have the following problem:

I have an php array looking like this:

```
$array = [
    [
        ['sales_count' => '2'],
        ['customer_id' => '1'],
    ],
    [
        ['sales_count' => '3'],
        ['customer_id' => '2'],
    ]
];
```

Now if I use json_encode on this array, I get the following result:

```
[[{"sales_count":"2"},{"customer_id":"1"}],[{"sales_count":"3"},{"customer_id":"2"}]]
```

However, I'm trying to get the following output: (an array of flat, associative arrays)

```
[{"sales_count":"2","customer_id":"1"},{"sales_count":"3","customer_id":"2"}]
```

Comment: you have 2D array and want to output 1D array. So you obviously first need to convert your array to 1D, then json_encode will get expected result

Comment: where's the code that creates the arrays...flatten it there

Comment: No, you dont want the result youre describing. I cant think of any useful scenario where you have duplicate data in same field names in same array. That might be a failing of my imagination perhaps, but still, I think your solution might not work, or, at the least, will cause more trouble than its worth.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu you obviously don't do much front end AJAX work with JSON API's

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really really new to this, but I think I do want that result. I'm pretty sure it's not the best to do this like you mentioned, but at I want this to work at least and clean it up later. And no, I really don't do much AJAX at all, but my next step is to try and learn how to do it.

Comment: @Sirence to send to client for use in javascript you are correct. If you need the current format to work in a javascript app it's not difficult either. Instead of dealing with `data` as an array, you would work with `data[0]`. Answers below will work for you

Comment: @charlietfl Not much with ajax, no, but I spent last few days trying to convert any delphi TObject, send it over to a server in JSON, and  convert it back. I like my data well defined. I think that converting the array in the way described can in best case save programmer a for loop, and in worst case mix up data and cause incorrect results.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu well don't get into front end single page application javascript then. Format shown is driving many many many web sites

Comment: @charlietfl correction: none of the answers prior to my new answer actually provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flatten the deep associative data in each "row", none of the previous answers work as required. Other techniques provided merely flatten the data to become an array of single-element associative rows (or worse destroy associative relationships while flattening). For the record, dynamically flattening an array's first level is more succinctly coded as `array_merge(...$array)`.

Instead, you must iterate all rows and specifically merge their subarrays.  This will flatten the deep structure only so that rows now have two associative elements.  THIS is what the question is actually asking for.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iFOr4))

```
echo json_encode(
         array_map(
             fn($a) => array_merge(...$a),
             $array
         )
     );
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the fact that there are two arrays inside your original array on indexes 0 and 1

You need to do something like this

```
$masterArray = Array (
 [0] => Array (
    [0] => Array ( [sales_count] => 2 )
    [1] => Array ( [customer_id] => 1 )
 ) 
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Array ( [sales_count] => 3 )
    [1] => Array ( [customer_id] => 2 ) 
 ) 
);

$json_array = array_merge($masterArray[0], $masterArray[1]);

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Syntax for the `$masterArray` maybe wrong but follow the concept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $json_array = array_merge($masterarray[0][0], $masterarray[0][1]); gives me what I need. How would I loop through this if I do not know how many entries each outer and inner array has?

Comment: use a loop starting with `$i = 0` until `$i` reaches `sizeof($masterarray[0])`. You want me to write the code for that also?

Comment: I'll try and if I don't manage to, I'll ask again if that is okay with you?

Answer (score 2):

on your array should be:

```
$data = array(
  array("sales_count" => 2),
  array("customer_id" => 1),
  array("sales_count" => 2),
  array("customer_id" => 1),
 );
json_encode($data);
```

for you to achieve your expected output.

**though if your array is correct you can access your json object by**

```
var data = [
   [
    {"sales_count":"2"},
    {"customer_id":"1"}
   ],
    [
     {"sales_count":"3"},
     {"customer_id":"2"}
    ]
 ];

data[0][0].sales_count will access sales_count = 2 on your 1st array.
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could restructure them and put them inside a new one. Example:

```
$new_array = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) use (&$new_array) {
    $new_array[] = array($key => $val);
});

$new_array = json_encode($new_array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
// [{"sales_count":2},{"customer_id":1},{"sales_count":3},{"customer_id":2}]
```

Or just a simple loop, just simply, push them inside:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    foreach($values as $val) {
        $new_array[] = $val;
    }
}

echo json_encode($new_array);
```

Sample output as above.

Answer (score 2):

**I come from VietNam. My English does not good. So, I write this code. I hope this help you.**

```
 $arr = array(
   0 => array(0 => array('sales_count'=>2),1 => array('customer_id' => 1)),
   1 => array(0 => array('sales_count'=>3),1 => array('customer_id' => 2)),
);
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $kvalue => $vvalue){
     $new_arr[] = $vvalue;
  }
}
print_r(json_encode($new_arr));
```